# Is it possible to export Quill data to document format

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

I started a project and I'm planning to use Quill in it. It has all the properties that interest me but I'm wondering about one that is not mentioned...:

- I would like to know if it's possible to export the entered text in a Quill Text Editor to a word document with the same text **formatting** (.docx format or .odt, whatever).

Here is the JSON generated by Quill when you enter a text:

```
{"ops":[
{"insert":"This is a big header"},
{"attributes":{"header":1},"insert":"\n"},
{"insert":"And this is a smaller header"},
{"attributes":{"header":2},
              "insert":"\n"},
              {"insert":"And this is plaintext\n"}
]}
```

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: A Google search for `javascript quill export to word` turns up mostly HTML based solutions so that may be your best bet at the moment

Comment: Hi @bedox ! So finally how did you do this ? I guess you get the HTML format but then how did you turn it in docx ? I'm encountering the same issue. Do you mind sharing your experience ? Thank you